# Are .ninja domains available?

Tags: domain-registration, top-level-domains

I am looking at `http://domains.ninja/fr/timeline/`, and I see that the top-level `.ninja` domain is in its last "stage".

But I can seem to find a ninja domain (other than `domains.ninja`). Is the domain actually available now? If not, when will it be.

Pardon me for any ignorance; it seems that a lot of the domain registration stuff is designed to take advantage of ignorance and is unclear.

Comment: Re-opened since you were not requesting an off-site resource. The [.ninja](http://icannwiki.com/index.php/.ninja) gLTD is currently available for registration. The registry is [Demand Media](http://icannwiki.com/index.php/Demand_Media), who operates several domain registrars - you can view these [here](http://www.demandmedia.com/services/).

Answer (score 3):

The TLD is indeed available.

coding.ninja is an example of an operating domain. (Though it seems broken...)