# Will .day TLD be available to the public?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, top-level-domains, availability

I am interested in getting a `.day` domain. However, I cannot seem to find it. IANA [says](https://gtldresult.icann.org/applicationstatus/applicationdetails/1334) it belongs to Google (through their subsidiary *Charleston Road Registry*), but Google domains says `.day` is not available.

Do we know when this will be available, and can I already reserve my desired domain name? If so, how?

---

This question is similar to several others on this site:

- [`.app`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/71350/112370),
- [`.data`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/125342/112370),
- [`.ninja`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/65435/112370),
- [`.blog`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/122268/112370) with some explanation about phases of going public,
- [`.book`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/121909/112370), which has a pretty good explanation, albeit specific to this TLD

So if you can give a cannonical answer, that's even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.day` domain is becoming available for the general public.

> The sunrise period runs from December 14, 2021 to January 25, 2022.
> During the sunrise period, Trademark owners may apply for Day-Domains
> of the same name. It is necessary to register the trademarks with the
> Trademark Clearinghouse.

[Source](https://www.domainregistry.de/day-domain.html)

The General Availability starts on February 1st, 2022.

Comment: Beautiful ! Thank you ! 
I suppose we can't place orders before january 25th for domains, right ? Do we at least know which registrars would offer domains on `.day` ?

Comment: Dear Ciprian,you can pre-register at us .day domains for the EAP and GA.https://www.domainregistry.de/day-domain.html

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă List of .day accredited registrars should appear at some point on registry own website: https://www.registry.google/register-a-domain/ ; Be very cautious of any pre-registration system however, make sure to read the fine print (and especially what happens if you need to pay upfront and if the name you wanted is not available for some reason and what then happens with your payment)

Comment: Better source of data than a specific registrar as it borders to self-promotion: ICANN own website showing dates of start at https://newgtlds.icann.org/en/program-status/sunrise-claims-periods?search_api_views_fulltext=day&sunrise_open%5Bdate%5D=&sunrise_close%5Bdate%5D=&field_gtld_sunrise_close=2  ; you don't have there details on EAP but all registrars have it now so contact your prefered registrar and ask it for its plans regarding this TLD. You can also look at specialized news sites: http://www.domainincite.com/27252-google-to-release-another-new-gtld-next-month

Comment: thank you, @PatrickMevzek!

Answer (score 7):

There is no possible canonical answer.

For 2012 new gTLD round, each applicant was coming with some kind of business plan, for what it wants to do with the TLD. Some are restricted to a brand, some to a geography, some are bound by other restrictions, and some are completely open.

If you go to https://gtldresult.icann.org/applicationstatus/viewstatus and then search by TLD (warning: they could be multiple applications per TLD and of course at most one is the winner), you can then view the initial registry plan. Of course it can have changed this then.

`.day` is  a Google TLD, like `.page`, `.dev`, `.app` or `.new` (that one goes live during this summer of 2020).

Google Registry is one registry not sharing a lot of their plan in advance. I, for one, have no public data on this TLD launch.

If you read their initial submission at https://gtldresult.icann.org/applicationstatus/applicationdetails/1334 you can read:

> 18.a. Mission⁄Purpose of the Proposed gTLD
>
> [..]
>
> The proposed gTLD will provide the marketplace with direct association
> to the term, ʺday.ʺ  The mission of this gTLD, .day, is to provide a
> dedicated domain space in which registrants can enact second-level
> domains that relate to memorable, special, or hallmark days and⁄or
> physical or online events.  This mission will enhance consumer choice
> by providing new availability in the second-level domain space,
> creating new layers of organization on the Internet, and signaling the
> kind of content available in the domain.  Charleston Road Registry
> believes that registrants will find value in associating with this
> gTLD, which could have a vast array of uses.  Charleston Road Registry
> expects these uses may include but are not limited to applications
> such as birth.day, christmas.day, wedding.day, rememberthat.day, and
> event.day.

By this reading one might get to the conclusion that it will be open to any registrant. One day :-)

The only obligation they have is to give ICANN details of their launch in advance.
This would happen here: https://newgtlds.icann.org/en/program-status/sunrise-claims-periods
There is nothing about `.day` there yet.

Note also that any knowledgeable registrar should be able to keep you in the loop as soon as it gets news for that TLD.

> can I already reserve my desired domain name?

Irrespective to all the above, you can't do that, in any 2012 gTLD.

Registries do not take "advance" reservations. Some registrar may make you believe so, and make you pay for it, but:

- registration requirements can be known only very close to opening, and can depend on the name chosen, so your choice might not even be possible
- since registries do not provide this service, registrars will keep your name and then try to register it at adequate time, however they will compete with all others so no guarantees for you whatsoever
- gTLDs open in rounds, with a mandatory sunrise, and possible EAP and LRP phases; the restrictions are different in each, as are the prices (which are also often not known precisely until very close to opening).

ICANN itself warns you about this case:
https://www.icann.org/news/blog/pre-reserve-a-domain-name-or-not-icann-answers-the-question

> As responsible Registrars are advising, successful pre-registration of
> a domain cannot be guaranteed. ICANN seconds that advice, cautioning
> that registrants should be wary of anyone who claims to be able to
> guarantee a domain registration on a new gTLD. There are several
> situations that can impact the availability of a domain name and some
> domain names may never be available for purchase.

Comment: Thank you for providing all the details ! Indeed, I was also under the impression that it will be public, [one day](http://one.day). You mention *that any knowledgeable registrar should be able to keep you in the loop as soon as it gets news for that TLD.* Can you please advise how to register for such news ? Most that I've checked simply say they do not offer any `.day` domains, with no further options

Comment: I just mean that multiple registrars do send information like this to their customers/prospective customers, because at the core they want to sell names :-) So if you find a registrar you like and it is prospective and tracking changes, you should get news about `day` when they have some. Based on previous Google launches they are taking time like 1 or 2 TLD per year. `new` comes this summer and `meet` has also just launched (but is closed), so I do not expect other TLDs from them this year, but I have no infomration.

Comment: You can also find "domain name" related news (and hence probably release announcements, but except if the registry announces publicly, the first ones to know are the registrars and ICANN) at various outlets such as http://domainincite.com/ or https://domainnamewire.com/

Comment: What does *.day is a Google TLD, like .page, .dev, .app or .new which one goes live during this summer of 2020.* mean? it seems like a word is missing

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I slightly rephrased things if it makes it clearer.

Comment: This answer is now out-of-date.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Yes, as are many others. It is hard to predict the future, isn't it? I think answers need to be read in context of the date they are written. Of course situations change and no one can expect all answers to be updated, it does not even make sense, for archival/historical reasons it is often good to just know how the state was at a certain date. Two answers were added later, adapted to their date with new information.

Comment: And beside the specific case, it conveys an important generic information that stays as relevant now as it was then: to the question of "When will X be available?" most often the answer is "It is not possible to know, one has to follow news and stay alert on it if interested" (and be specially cautious from registrars or third party news that are biaised).  The ICANN warning at the end is also important to convey in my eyes. New gTLDs will come, ICANN has a process for that, so we are bound to get again the same kind of questions.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Please don't take my comment personally! I generally like to comment like this to signal to readers to scroll down because there is more up-to-date information to be had. However, you are right that your answer is designed to be canonical and apply to not just `.day` but to new gTLDs in general. If I had read the question more carefully before commenting, I would have also realized that it specifically asked for a canonical answer. Not saying that your answer is bad or anything (its' great)! And perhaps my comment here wasn't very useful, in retrospect.

Answer (score 2):

From the [2021-11-05 registry.google blogpost about the release](https://www.registry.google/announcements/launch-details-for-dot-day/):

> Here are the important dates to be aware of (all phases begin and end
> at 16:00 UTC) :
>
> - Dec 14th, 2021 - Jan 25th, 2022: Sunrise, where trademark holders who
>   have submitted their trademark to the Trademark Clearinghouse can
>   register .day domains.
> - Jan 25th, 2022 - Feb 1, 2022: Early Access Period (EAP), where anyone can register available .day domains for an extra fee, which decreases leading up
>   to General Availability.
> - Feb 1st, 2022 and onwards: General Availability, where anyone can register
>   available .day domains without paying an EAP fee. Please note that a claims
>   period will run indefinitely, during which trademark owners will receive
>   notification when their marks are registered as domains.